# Select a word in Notepad++ by hotkey

Tags: notepad++, selection

For some reason when I double click a word in Notepad++, the whole sentence (between `.,"'()!?`) is selected instead of single word.
The same is when I use `Ctrl + Shift + Left` or `Ctrl + Shift + Right`.

[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]

Settings-Preferences-Delimiter-Word character list is set to `Use default Word character list as it is`.

I can't find what option is wrong.

Here's About screen:
[image: about]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any updates available to Notepad++? If not, re-install with 64-Bit (providing your machine isn't 32-Bit!) and try again from there.

Comment: No updates, it's already 64-Bit version 7.3.3

Comment: Hmmmm okay, I definitely think removing Notepad++ from Add and Remove programs and then re-installing is a good shot. In theory that should default any settings that could have changed causing this issue.

Comment: Wow! I've found that Notelad++ tells me that there're no updates, but there's 7.4.2 version on official site! I've installed it and all works! Thank you! :)

Comment: Interesting! Give that a shot and keep your fingers crossed for now, I would presume that has a good chance of resolving the problem.